# jQuery small inline kind of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tabular/grid data with 7-8 cols..

Now the col string values are displayed for each col and there is inline edit (div -> textbox -> div), except for one for which I display an edit icon..since this col has large text, so  cannot display the value as part of that same grid..

Now I want the same functionality to be applied for this col...but on click of edit icon...i.e. on click of edit icon, a textarea is displayed with the value and may a Ok button on click of which I save the value...

I am not sure what is the best way to implement the same? Should I open a separate popup next to the Edit icon ?

**I know there are a lot of plugins like X-editable and others, but I CANNOT use any custom plugin...**

I want to write custom code...

Comment: Try referring idea used by handsontable (handsontable.com)

Comment: This has all inline edits...like i said..in my case, since text is long...i want that edit to happen in a separate dialog....also i cannot use any plugins...

Comment: You can provide either as a dialogue box as in jQuery UI or use the same technique as in handson where instead of a text-box try inserting a div with text-area and button